# Check if Page Loaded Completely - Puppeteer C#

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I use this code to wait the page to load complety:

```
await page.GoToAsync(url, requestTimeout, new WaitUntilNavigation[]
                                {
                                   WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0
                                });
```

it will wait and works like a charm, But I need to remove `WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0` and not wait for completion. But I need to check somewhere else if the page is loaded completely or it is still in the loading state. How to achieve this?

Comment: Don't you have a selector to use as a hint? A DOM element showing up? with that, you can use WaitForSelectorAsync

Comment: No, I do not :(

Comment: As a user, How do you know when the page is loaded?

Comment: As hardkoded asked, when do you know it's loaded in your own browser? The definition of a page being loaded depends greatly on the site and on why you need to know that it's loaded. The `Networkidle2` wait strategy might be better if you do not need to wait until completion as you stated. The network may never be completely idle for some XHR heavy sites.

Comment: I'm using it in headless mode, the user will enter a URL, and then the rest of the algorithm will be executed. so I can not decide what should happen in that URL to detect the state. but the chrome browser will show a loading indicator on the tab and when the browser finished loading that indicator will be stable. So I think maybe there is such a property to detect the loading and compelte state.